# Chemistry books for the general reader

Tags: books

I’m quite interested in chemistry, but reading the textbooks are a bit challenging. Are there any good chemistry books for the general reader that go a bit beyond the basics?

Comment: Check out [Resources for learning Chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/37303/resources-for-learning-chemistry). Probably you'll find something not only for general Reader, but also for major Curiosity:)

Comment: What do you mean by "challenging" ? Too simple ? Too difficult? What ? What is "beyond the the basics" for you ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resources for learning Chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/37303/resources-for-learning-chemistry)

Comment: Do you know Sir Michael Caine's word as father Robert Spritzel in the 2005 movie «The Weather Man» to his son?  To quote: «Do you know, that the harder thing to do, and the right thing to, were usually the same thing?  Easy does not enter in the grown-up life.  To get any thing of value, you have to sacrifice.»  It is around 1:28 min to 1:45 min of this preview here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vZIIKsnM6MM.

Comment: I suppose you mean "popular science"? It much depends on what branch of chemistry you are interested in, traditionally: analytical, organic, inorganic, physical. (others include polymer, materials, surface ...)